# Inline class member functions

Tags: c++

The instruction I was given is:
Write the class declaration for the KiloZorb class, derived from the Zorb base class. Within your class declaration, show the implementation of the KiloZorb value constructor as an inline function, implemented in terms of the base class Zorb constructor. Recall that the new KiloZorb will have 1/1000 of the power indicated by the power parameter.

What is meant by "inline" in this context?

```
// The Zorb game - the base class
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Zorb {
    public:
         // value constructor
         Zorb(int p, int t) : _power(p), _team_id(t) {}
         bool operator< (const Zorb&) const;
         Zorb operator+ (const Zorb&) const;
         int getPower() { return _power; }
         int getTeamID() { return _team_id; }
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Zorb&);
    private:
         int _power;
         int _team_id;
};

// derived class
class KiloZorb: public Zorb {
    public:
};

// operator< usage: Zorb z1, z2; if (z1 < z2) {}
// In the expression z1<z2, "this" Zorb is z1 (the left operand).
// Returns true if "this" Zorb (left operand) has a different team ID
// AND greater power than the other Zorb (right operand).

bool Zorb::operator< (const Zorb& z) const {
    if (this->_team_id == z._team_id)
         return false;
    else
         return this->_power < z._power;
}

// operator+ usage: Zorb z3 = z1 + z2;
// Constructs a new Zorb (here assigned to z3) with the combined power
// of the original two Zorbs (z1 and z2), and the team ID of the stronger of
// the original two Zorbs.
// In the expression z1+z2, "this" Zorb is z1 (the left operand).

Zorb Zorb::operator+ (const Zorb& z) const {
    return Zorb(this->_power + z._power,
                ((*this < z) ? z._team_id : this->_team_id) );
}
```

Comment: "inline function" probably means "put the definition of the constructor inside the class definition"

Comment: Q: How can I implement KiloZorb value constructor as an inline function?  A:   Botje is correct.  Typically, you'd just include a method's implementation directly in the class definition.  You could also use the "inline" keyword.  Look here for more details:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-functions-cpp/

Answer (score 0):

There are two things referred to as `inline` in C++.

The first one is the `inline` keyword, which goes in front of a function definition like this:

```cpp
inline return_type function_name(function_parameters) {
    // code
}
```

This function will be copied as is in every "call", so in essence will not get called from memory, thus improving the performance of the program at the cost of greater executable size (as many copies of the function code will exist in the executable).

The second use of the term inline is about a class.
When you have a class, you can either define the member functions of the class inside the class definition like this:

```cpp
class class_name {
    return_type function_name(function_parameters) {
        // code
    }
}
```

or outside of it:

```cpp
class class_name {
    return_type function_name(function_parameters);
    
}

class_name::function_name(function_parameters) {
    // code
}
```

The first way i showed is called inline definition of a member function and is usually used for functions with little code, like getters and setters.